# Why FileSystemXmlApplicationContext throws FileNotFoundException on file that exists

Tags: java, linux, spring

I'm running the following code:

```
new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/data/farm/Server/confData/1000004/contex.xml")
```

and it throws

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [data/farm/Server/confData/1000004/contex.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The file exists, I can do

```
cat /data/farm/Server/confData/1000004/contex.xml
```

and see its content.
Also in windows this code is working - the problem is in linus (i have ubuntu os)

Can any one advise what is wrong here?

Comment: Check this out http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37155-Path-problem-with-FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try creating a FileSystemXmlApplicationContext using a Url, like:

```
new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:/data/farm/Server/confData/1000004/contex.xml");
```

For further explanation see this: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html 5.7.3 FileSystemResource caveats

Comment: I've tried to do the same , it works when I'm running the code from IDE , but it doesn't work when I compile jar file and trying to execute it, getting the fileNotFoundException. Any idea , what went wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe because of that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483160/spring-filesystemxmlapplicationcontext-dont-find-the-bean-configuration-file-an

Comment: @IstvanDevai the answer in this thread is the same , use "file:" as prefix... that's what I did