# Spring FileSystemXmlApplicationContext don't find the bean configuration file and go into error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I am trying to do the following Spring "Hello World" example that use the **FileSystemXmlApplicationContext** as implementation of ApplicationContext interface.

This implementation have to take the **full path of the XML bean configuration** as constructor parameter, something like the previous example:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:/Users/ZARA/workspace/HelloSpring/src/Beans.xml");
```

I use Linux and my Beans configuration file is under the following path:
**/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml**, so in my code I have:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml");
```

The problem is that when I try to run my application, in the STS\Eclipse console I have the following error message (seems that don't find the file):

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml (File o directory non esistente)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.andrea.myexample.myapplicationcontextexample.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/src/main/java/Beans.xml (File o directory non esistente)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Why? How can I solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: It looks like its using your home directory, then appending the extra path information to it.  Try changing the code to read: ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/main/java/Beans.xml");

Comment: Ok, now work well...but why automatically use have defined this path: "/home/andrea/Documents/ws/myapplicationcontextexample/"?

Comment: In java, there is a system-level property, which I believe is called "user.dir", which is the current working directory for your app.  In the case of Eclipse, I believe it defaults to the project's folder.  You can modify the starup directory in the Eclipse launch settings, I believe.

Answer (score 8):

> **NOTE**: Plain paths will always be interpreted as relative to the current VM working directory, even if they start with a slash. (This is consistent with the semantics in a Servlet container.) **Use an explicit "file:" prefix to enforce an absolute file path.**

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html

Comment: gr8 it worked on Ubuntu. earlier i was wondering why FileSystemXmlApplicationContext works on windows but not on Linux!!!