# "file:d:\\dir1\file.xml" and "file:/d:\\dir1\file.xml" as FileSystemXmlApplicationContext arguments

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring from a non-server application (just compile and run it from main() of some class in Eclipse).

My question is what is acceptable as an argument of new [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html)?

This argument is a String. I don't see any URI/URL constructor.

But is accepts not only "d:\dir1\file.xml", but also "file:d:\dir1\file.xml" and "file:/d:\dir1\file.xml" - why? And can I rely on that everywhere (say on Linux, I tested it just on Windows). Is it OK to use "file: sth" in this String argument?

```
String metadata = "D:\\mybean.xml";  // fine!
String metadata = "file:D:\\mybean.xml";  // fine!
String metadata = "file:/D:\\mybean.xml"; // fine
String metadata1 = "file://D:\\mybean.xml"; // resource not found
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext( metadata );
```

P.S. As [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) states:

> NOTE: *Plain paths* will always be *interpreted as relative to the
>   **current VM working directory***, even if they start with a slash. (This
>   is consistent with the semantics in a Servlet container.) *Use an
>   explicit "file:" prefix to enforce an absolute file path.*

"Plain path" - seems to be anything like "dir1/dir2/file.xml" (without leading slash or file: ).

Besides, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483160/spring-filesystemxmlapplicationcontext-dont-find-the-bean-configuration-file-an?rq=1) that `/home/dir1/file.xml` won't work on *Linux* (while `C:\\dir1\\file.xml` worked on *Windows*) because `/home` - is not absolute from root!!!

Comment: If that helped you, then please mark it as "answered" to help other people see that you found the answer and it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct. It accepts `configLocation` in this particular case.

For more use cases you could take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html#FileSystemXmlApplicationContext-java.lang.String-) for `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`.

#### Sidenote

Take into account, that a better way will be to work with [Paths.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and then just get the location from that `Path` instance.